# iPhone simulator on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, web-browser

When using an iPad if you download and use an iphone application, an iphone outline will appear on the screen with the application inside.

[image]

I'm looking for a way to switch between viewing websites normally as they would appear on the iPad and iphone view.

What would be the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download an iPad browser, such as [Dolphin Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dolphin-browser/id452204407?mt=8) or [Opera Mini](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/opera-mini-web-browser/id363729560?mt=8).
Then download a web browser that is iPhone/iPod touch only, such as [Mango Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/mango-browser-web-browser/id312259486?mt=8), [iFox FREE](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ifox-free-browser-fullscreen/id448166251?mt=8), [Sphere](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sphere-web-browser-lite/id365755803?mt=8), or [Full Screen Web Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/full-screen-web-browser/id303154925?mt=8) (99¢). Then you can run an iPad browser in the full iPad mode and run another browser that is in the 1x 2x iPhone mode.

Comment: If you can find the a good app for this I will mark it answered.

Comment: @PhilipK Added links.

Comment: iFox seems to be the best of the lot. Though there is some room for improvement. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilipK Awesome! Glad I could help!

Comment: Any new updates on this? I want to keep my iPhone 5 sized phone, but would love to test iPhone 6 and 6+ in a native way - on an iPad. Thanks.

Comment: Any news for this?